# Using dictionary comprehension with ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-2.7

With the following example, I'm able to get the values from `[section1]`.  How I can do this for the other sections, or for more sections?

**store.config**

```
[section1]
field_a = hello
field_b = galaxy

[section2]
field_a = hello
field_b = galaxy

[section3]
field_a = hello
field_b = galaxy
```

**mainfile.py**

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

class Main:

   def get_properties(self, section, *variables):
        cfgFile = 'c:\store.config'
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read(cfgFile)
        properties= variables
        return {
            variable: parser.get(section,variable) for variable in properties
        }

   def run_me(self):
        config_vars= self.get_properties('section1','field_a')
        print config_vars

op=Main()
op.run_me()
```

current output:

```
{'section1': 'field_a'}
```

This will help me improve the solution given at the post [Using var from from function A to function B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730524/using-var-from-from-function-a-to-function-b).

Comment: Why do you pass `"field_a"` and `"field_b"` as parameters to `get_properties` **AND** assign them as literals inside the same  function to `properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
def run_me(self):
    config_vars= self.get_properties('services','package_install','package_info')
    convig_vars_2 = self.get_properties('network','proxy_server','proxy_user')
```

Simply as that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [the `sections` method](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.sections) of your `SafeConfigParser`.  For your example, it should return `['section1', 'section2', 'section3']`, which you can iterate over.

Comment: Not a direct answer , but still helped me to figure out the solution.

Comment: I don't see how the answer you added solved the problem.  I assumed you were looking for a flexible method to identify the sections in the configuration file, based on your statement "...I'm able to get the values from `[section1]`. How I can do this for the other sections, or for more sections?"  I guess I assumed since you were using `'section1'` as a parameter to `get_properties`, you were looking to enumerate the other section names so that you could flexibly query them all in a similar fashion.  Did I entirely misunderstand your question?